# PHP Calculator Operator

Tags: php, function, calculator

I´ve a very scary problem with my PHP-Code. If I use the operators "+" or "-" the program doesn´t show me the full calculating. 
What i wanna see(Works with the operators "*" and "/"):
1+3=4
What I see:
4
It´s exactly the same code in the functions and the if-queries(except of the "+" instead of "/").PHP doesn´t give me Errors in the /var/log file.
How can i solve that in masterfully way?

Best regards!

**MY CODE:**

```
<?php
function addition($a, $b) {
    echo $a . "+" . $b . "=" . $a + $b;
}

function subtraktion($a, $b) {
    echo $a . "-" . $b . "=" . $a - $b;
}

function multiplikation($a, $b) {
    echo $a . "*" . $b . "=" . $a * $b;
}

function division($a, $b) {
    echo $a . "/" . $b . "=" . $a / $b;
}

if (($_GET['op']) == "+") {
    addition($_GET['azahl'], $_GET['bzahl']);
}
if (($_GET['op']) == "-") {
    subtraktion($_GET['azahl'], $_GET['bzahl']);
}
if (($_GET['op']) == "*") {
    multiplikation($_GET['azahl'], $_GET['bzahl']);
}
if (($_GET['op']) == "/") {
    division($_GET['azahl'], $_GET['bzahl']);
}
?>
```

Comment: you can separate the actual operations with parenthesis: `echo $a."/".$b."=".($a/$b);`

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses, because the default operator precedence doesn't do what you need:

```
function addition($a,$b)
{   
    echo(($a."+".$b."=").($a+$b));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast `(string)` on parameters and encapsulate in parenthesis:

```
function addition($a,$b)
{   
    echo (string)$a."+".(string)$b."=".($a+$b);
}
function subtraktion($a,$b)
{
    echo (string)$a."-".(string)$b."=".($a-$b);
}
function multiplikation($a,$b)
{
    echo (string)$a."*".(string)$b."=".($a*$b);
}
function division($a,$b)
{
    echo (string)$a."/".(string)$b."=".($a/$b);
}
```

Comment: @Harald Wiesinger`.` and `+` or `-` have the same precedence, pointed out in a php doc comment, see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#41950) for further explainations. This answer should work...